# Unique word count in C++ help?

Tags: c++, function, word-count

I would like to do a function which can count the unique words. For example:

"I like to program something useful. And I like to eat. Eat ice-cream now."

In this case, each unique words:

```
I occurs 2
like occurs 2
...
```

I will ignore the case later on. Please help

EDIT:

I have finished write the functions. It works perfectly. Thanks for all the help. Very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you want to use an [std::map](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/Map.html) with a key string and data of int.

If an item doesn't exist in the map already you add it with an int value of 1.  If the item does exist in the map already you simply add 1 to its associated value.

Comment: i see. if I am using map, will i be able to sort it out later? like sort by frequenzy

Comment: could you please, guide me, if my scenario is similar to this: http://forum.codecall.net/c-c/3162-need-help-w-word-count-program-asap.html. I need it very urgent

Comment: @cpp_learner: If you are unsure of some other aspect you can put in another question about what is confusing you.

Comment: @Brian R. Bond: You can't sort a std::map. You can instantiate it with a custom sort function though.

Comment: When you access an index for the first time it will be initialized to zero. So the simple solution is just to always 1

Answer (score 1):

I'll treat this as a homework question (hopefully no-one will be so thoughtless as to present complete code).

If you're content with a very loose definition of "word", then iostream input already splits the input into words for you.

Then use e.g. `std::map` to count distinct words.

Cheers & hth.,

Comment: oh ya, i dont expect a complete code. A sample code of using map etc will do. I will go explore more by myself later on

Comment: @cpp_learner: For examples on how to use `std::map` or any other std library construct in C++, see http://cplusplus.com/reference/

Answer (score 1):

It is an excellent opportunity to get acquainted with iterators and standard algorithms.

There is [`std::istream_iterator`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/iterator/istream_iterator/) which iterates on the list of words drawn from a given stream, either `std::cin` or a file or a string.

There is [`std::unique`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/unique/) which can help you in your goal.

Example program:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;


int main()
{
    istream_iterator<string> begin(cin), end;
    vector<string> tmp;

    copy(begin, end, back_inserter(tmp));
    sort(tmp.begin(), tmp.end());
    vector<string>::iterator it = unique(tmp.begin(), tmp.end());

    cout << "Words:\n";
    copy(tmp.begin(), it, ostream_iterator<string>(cout));
}
```

Please refer to http://www.cplusplus.com for further reference on the standard library.

Comment: Nice try: But istream_iterator<string> defines words as being space separated. Which is fine for most contexts. But here punctuation will come into play. Also why use a vector when a map will automatically sort and count the content as it comes in.