# Word count in c++ after using (getline(cin,input))?

Tags: c++, string, set, substring, word-count

So i am extremely new to this. I have an assignment to count the number of lines, words, characters, unique lines and unique words from user input. So far I have gotten lines, unique lines and characters from my code. I thought I got the words but then it doesn't work when i factor in double spaces and tabs. Also i have no clue how to find the unique words. Please offer your assistance.

Code:

```
 // What I dont have:
//words
//Total words


#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <set>
using namespace std;


unsigned long countWords(const string& s, set<string>& wl);  //total words

int main()
{
     int linenum=0, charnum=0, totalwords=0;
     set<string> lines;
     string input;
     set<string> unique;   //to store unique words from countWords function

while (getline(cin,input))
    {
         lines.insert(input);
         linenum++; 

         charnum+= input.length();


         totalwords += countWords(input,unique);        
    }

    cout << linenum <<"     "<< totalwords <<"     "<< charnum <<"     " << lines.size()<<"     "         << unique.size()<< endl;

         system("PAUSE"); 
     return 0;
}

unsigned long countWords(const string& s, set<string>& wl) //total words        
{
     int wcount=1;         


     for (unsigned int i=0; i < s.length(); i++)
     {   

          if ((s.at(i) == ' ')&&(s.at(i)+1 !='\0')) {
                         wcount++;

                         }

      }    


return wcount;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to count characters, lines, and words in a file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18647903/how-to-count-characters-lines-and-words-in-a-file)

Comment: @Suyog it is similar, with the added requirement of finding unique words

Comment: Look into `std::map` see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4238395/unique-word-count-in-c-help

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how the function could look

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <set>
#include <string>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>


unsigned long countWords( std::set<string> &wl, const std::string &s )  
{
    std::istringstream is( s );
    wl.insert( std::istream_iterator<std::string>( is ),
               std::istream_iterator<std::string>() );

    is.clear();
    is.str( s );

    return ( std::distance( std::istream_iterator<std::string>( is ),
                            std::istream_iterator<std::string>() ) );
}

//...
```

In this example puctuations are considered as parts of words.

If you do not know yet std::istringstream and other facilities of C++ then you can write the function the following way

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <string>


unsigned long countWords( std::set<string> &wl, const std::string &s )  
{
    const char *white_space = " \t";
    unsigned long count = 0;

    for ( std::string::size_type pos = 0, n = 0; 
          ( pos = s.find_first_not_of( white_space, pos ) ) != std::string::npos;
          pos = n == std::string::npos ? s.size() : n )
    {
        ++count;
        n = s.find_first_of( white_space, pos );
        wl.insert( s.substr( pos, ( n == std::string::npos ? std::string::npos : n - pos ) ) );
    }

    return count;
}

//...
```

Comment: I don't have knowledge of any of the libraries or w/e used here. An instructor advised using a substring; keeping track of the previous and next whitespace to compute the parameters for the substring. However I draw blanks even thinking about hoe to approach this.

Comment: @jdreamin May you use std::vector?

Comment: Yes I can. The instructor explicitly stated that I cannot use strtok().

Comment: If it helps another approach I came up with is to (i) use a for loop to go through the string (ii) if a whitespace (ws) is found store that index as an int wsloc. (iii) insert all the characters from the last ws to the new ws into the set wl.

Comment: However I have no clue how to update the ws location or how to insert characters from the last ws index into the set wl

Comment: thanks it worked except for line.find.... which should be s.find. Also perhaps you could comment the lines explaining the code

Comment: @jdreamin It was a typo. I upadted the post.

Answer (score 0):

you need to put +1 inside brackets,your function will be like that

```
unsigned long countWords(const string& s, set<string>& wl) //total words        
{
     int wcount=0;// initial value must be zero
     int N = 0;// you need to add this to count the characters of each word.
     for (unsigned int i=0; i < s.length(); i++)
     {   
          if ((s.at(i) == ' ')||(s.at(i+1) =='\0')) {// Condition must be or instead of and
                 wl.insert(s.substr(i-N-1,N));
                 ++wcount;
                 N = 0;
              }else ++N;

      }    
return wcount;
}
```

Comment: Thanks much but this approach gives the same result as my initial one.

Comment: for example: if I type hello followed by two spaces, the word count returns 3 when it is supposed to return 1 ignoring the spaces and tabs

Comment: try this if(N!=0){++wcount;wl.insert(s.substr(i-N-1,N));}

Comment: That prints 0 for the word count and 0 for the unique words

Comment: you must do the condition before N=0;